# Kendo chart y axis label problems

Tags: asp.net-mvc, charts, kendo-ui, kendo-chart

I am having trouble with the y axis labels of a Kendo chart.

If I have large values there, it displays fine, it adapts and shows labels stepping accordingly: say the values go from 0 to 100, the labels step automatically like 0, 20, 40, 60, 80, 100. All good.

But for lower values, they get repeated, as shown below:

[image: Repeated]

After some research, I tried to set the `MajorUnit` property to 1, for example, and it fixed it for lower values:

```
        .ValueAxis(axis => axis.Numeric()
            .Labels(l => l.Format("N0"))
            .MajorGridLines(lines => lines.Visible(true))
            .MajorTicks(lines => lines.Visible(true))
            .MajorUnit(1) // <----------- this one
```

[image: low values fixed]

However, for the high values, it makes a label for every single one, causing some overlapping:

[image: high values screwed up]

I can't set the MajorUnit on dataBound as I have multiple series in the chart, some ranging from 0 to 2 and others from 0 to 200.

How can I fix this?

Comment: What if you format the label to allow one decimal place and then allow the step to be calculated automatically by the chart?

Comment: I tried something like that @ezanker, but no luck

Answer (score 2):

You have to adjust the 'categoryAxis.labels.step' dynamically on Chart 'dataBound' event

```
function dataBound(e) {
var chart = $("#chart").data("kendoChart");
if ([*MajorUnitData*].length > 4) {
    chart.options.categoryAxis.labels.step = 10;
}
else {
    chart.options.categoryAxis.labels.step = 1;
}
```

}

Refer this link : http://mikaelkoskinen.net/post/kendoui-dataviz-tips-and-tricks

Comment: Yep, that is good when you only have one series. That way, regardless of it returning 5 or 5000 records, you can set the step accordingly (+1). But my issue is that I have multiple series, with different ranges of values, so if I set the step to suit one, I will not suit the other one

Comment: You can take and min and max for the combined values of all the series and adjust the Label step.

Comment: Well, what would you suggest for the step value if I have series that range from 0 to 3 and others from 0 to 200?

Comment: In this case you can try multiple X/Y axes: http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/charts/overview#multiple-xy-axes and http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/bar-charts/multiple-axes

Comment: Thanks for your effort but I can't change the layout of the graph

Answer (score 0):

I would set chart height proportional to category axis count

```
dataBound: function (e) {
                var axis = e.sender.options.categoryAxis;
                $(e.sender.element).css("height", axis.categories.length * 45);
                $(e.sender.element).data("kendoChart").redraw();
              }
```

Comment: I can't change the layout of the page, otherwise, I would have. Thanks for the suggestion though